# The usage of the words “Decagon” and “vertex”

Tags: word-usage

I am writing a blog in which I present a 10-element model of “motivation”. That is to say, I have identified ten components which affect the motivation in people. The audience of this blog is laypeople (general public). Now my questions are

1-is the word “Decagon” or the phrase “motivation decagon” understandable for laypeople? what percent of native English readers know that ‘decagon’ refers to a 10-sided shape?

2-then, to explain the system, I’m going to use the word “vertex” to refer to each of these ten components. e.g:
Vertex 1: emotion
Vertex 2: thoughts
.
.
.
again, is ‘vertex’ a normal and totally understandable word for native English-speaking laypeople or I’d better use words like “angle” or “apex”?

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: Answers will be matters of opinion, so the question may be closed. By creating this geometric description of your ideas you shift the reader’s attention from your analysis of motivation to a diversionary and obscure way of saying that you have ten elements to consider. As you clearly realise, you also risk alienating those many readers who do not know or care about dodecahedrons or vertices. Your “model” is nothing more than saying that you consider ten elements.

Comment: Expanding on what @Anton said: a **decagon** is not just a collection of ten vertices - those vertices are in a particular arrangement with some vertices adjacent to each other and others quite distant. Unless this adjacency has meaning in your model, then using such precise geometric terminology could be a distraction from the model you are trying to describe.

Answer (score 2):

The usage aspect of the question is fairly easily answered. OED puts *decagon* in "frequency band 3":

[image: Screenshot of OED frequency band]

> This word belongs in Frequency Band 3. Band 3 contains words which occur between 0.01 and 0.1 times per million words in typical modern English usage. These words are not commonly found in general text types like novels and newspapers, but at the same they are not overly opaque or obscure. Nouns include ebullition and merengue, and examples of adjectives are amortizable, prelapsarian, contumacious, agglutinative, quantized, argentiferous...

While more people than 1 in ten million may know that *decagon* is a ten-sided figure, it crops up rarely and when it does it's highly likely to mean "a ten-sided shape". Thus using the word in a metaphorical or figurative way is probably not going to be helpful.

*Vertex* is in frequency band 5:

> This word belongs in Frequency Band 5. Band 5 contains words which occur between 1 and 10 times per million words in typical modern English usage. These tend to be restricted to literate vocabulary associated with educated discourse, although such words may still be familiar within the context of that discourse. The shift away from the everyday language found in bands 8-6 is apparent in nouns (e.g. surveillance, assimilation, tumult, penchant, paraphrase, admixture)...

That word is around a hundred times more commonly used than *decagon,* but it tends "to be restricted to literate vocabulary associated with educated discourse, [even though] such words may still be familiar within the context of that discourse." Again, using the word in a metaphorical or figurative way for a lay audience is probably not going to be helpful.

I'm not going to opine on what you ought to use instead, as that's opinion-based writing advice, which we don't do.

Comment: Neat and thorough response that sticks to the point, although reinforcing my commented opinion.

Comment: As there will be a picture of the decagon, I think the rarity of the word need not be of much concern. Once it has been referred to, the rest will flow,

Comment: @Greybeard There is absolutely no indication in the question that there will be an image of a decagon.

Comment: Perhaps I am over interpreting "I present a 10-element model of “motivation”." Blogs often have images.